# How to add charts to a React.js app without using a totally different coding style?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, reactjs, react-native

Is there a charting library that jives with how React.js asks you to do things? It seems like the chart should be a component.

D3.js seems to be the most powerful charting library out there, but it requires a lot of direct DOM work, which is the exact opposite of React.

Would there be a way to get those two libraries to play nice with each other? If not, is there an alternative to D3 that *does* work well with React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout high charts react library. https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts

Comment: I'd prefer something open source if possible. And from that demo, it doesn't look like it's tied very closely to react.

Comment: Not sure if this tied more closely, but there is also a component for adding ZingChart to React projects. https://github.com/zingchart/ZingChart-React (not open source, but another option)

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, I have found that by far the best way to render charts in RN is via a WebView. I worked on a cross-platform solution for messaging between RN and the WebView: https://github.com/jjshammas/react-native-webview-bridge

Alternatively, you may want to look into ReactART, which is unfortunately generally undocumented when it comes to using it in ReactNative. It does have a very strong relationship with RN, though it does not have all of the functionality of traditional vector rendering libraries. Take a look: http://browniefed.com/blog/2015/10/14/react-native-morphing-svg-paths-with-react-art/